# How to connect Spring boot API to elasticsearch via loadbalancer

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, load-balancing, elastic-load-balancer

**Overview:**

This is my current elastic configs in application.yml file:

```
# ELASTICSEARCH
elasticsearch:
  index: iom
  clusterName: ElasticsearchCluster
  host: host.linux.test.com 
  httpPort: 9300
  tcpPort: 9200
```

**Question:**

How could I update this configs to connect to elastic server via loadbalancer?

Loadbalancer info:

```
host: loadbalancer.test.com
username: user
password: pass
```

As I'm new in Spring boot and elastic, I would appreciate if you could share your solutions with me.

Comment: Create a internal load balancer add the nodes to that internal LB and then point your domain to that load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but would it be possible for you to explain it a bit more? I'm new to Spring boot and loadbalancer.